# copy from one mysql DB to another and separate table data into different tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to merge some data but beyond the basics I get a bit lost.

I have this..

```
INSERT INTO NewDB.Custs(Customer_ID) SELECT CustID FROM OldDB.Custs
```

Moving past this how would I increase the selection to add more?

Here's the basic layout of what I have right now.

OldDB = This is the Old DataBase that has the data
NewDB = New Database where the Data goes into

```
|===========|==|===========|==|=============|==|===========|
|OldDB.Custs|..|NewDB.Custs|..|NewDB.Details|..|NewDB.Notes|
|===========|==|===========|==|=============|==|===========|
|CustomerID |>>|Customer_ID|>>|Customer_ID  |>>|Customer_ID|
|CompanyName|>>|CompanyName|..|.............|..|...........|
|CFirstName |>>|FirstName  |..|.............|..|...........|
|CLastName  |>>|LastName   |..|.............|..|...........|
|HowDidHear |>>|>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|HowHear_ID   |..|...........|
|Notes      |>>|>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|>>>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|CustNotes  |
|Times      |>>|>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|>>>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|NoteTime   |
|Profession |>>|>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|Category_ID  |..|...........|
|DefPmtMeth |>>|>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|DefaultPaymt |..|...........|
|Deactivated|>>|>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|Deactivated  |..|...........|
|SalesRep   |>>|>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|SalesRep_ID  |..|...........|
|CertSent   |>>|>>>>>>>>>>>|>>|CertSent     |..|...........|
|===========|==|===========|==|=============|==|===========|
```

This is a diagram of what I'm trying to do.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the more experienced SQL gurus will probably chime in with a better way, but you could always:

```
INSERT INTO NewDB.Custs (
  Customer_ID, CompanyName, FirstName,  LastName)
SELECT
  CustomerID,  CompanyName, CFirstName, CLastName
FROM OldDB.Custs

INSERT INTO NewDB.Details (
  Customer_ID, HowHear_ID, Category_ID, DefaultPaymt, Deactivated,
  SalesRep_ID, CertSent)
SELECT
  CustomerID,  HowDidHear, Profession,  DefPmtMeth,   Deactivated,
  SalesRep,    CertSent
FROM OldDB.Custs

INSERT INTO NewDB.Notes (
  Customer_ID, CustNotes, NoteTime)
SELECT
  CustomerID,  Notes,     Times
FROM OldDB.Custs
```